# Process.GetProcessessByName doesnt work

Tags: c#, process

i have just made an updater whihch also controls if app running.

```
Process[] processOfApp = Process.GetProcessesByName(setting.ExeName);
if (processOfApp.Length == 0)
{
     Program = StartProcess(realPath + "\\" + setting.ExeName + ".exe");
     AppDir = realPath + "\\" + setting.ExeName + ".exe";
     ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser(AppDir);  
}
```

If no app process then start process. But these code start multiple instances.

What i did wrong?

Edit: these code block is in while(true) and this is the only start process in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have copied this from somewhere without knowing what it does? I am guessing `StartProcess` function starts a process. And I assume, so does `ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser`. So yes, it would start multiple (two) processes instead of one. If the updater should run a program for the current user from a windows service, delete the `Program = ...` line and retrive that information later on (using `Process.GetProcessesByName`, for example), if it is needed for something. That way the updater will be run as Current User, which is probably what you want.

```
 // This line starts an instance
 Program = StartProcess(realPath + "\\" + setting.ExeName + ".exe");
 AppDir = realPath + "\\" + setting.ExeName + ".exe";
 // This line also starts an instance
 ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser(AppDir);
```

Comment: Actually no. Only function which starts a process is this block.

Comment: @MarijkeBuurlage - this answer is attempting to point out that there are *two* function calls in that block that both look like they attempt to start a process. Either `StartProcess` and/or `StartProcessAsCurrentUser` are *really* badly named or you're trying to start two processes.

Comment: yeah right. I have totally missed that. When StartProcess open app in background i have added the startProcessAsUser and forget that, my bad, my silly. Thank you for support.